# Packets not hitting POSTROUTING rule, leaving interface unedited

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat

I am trying to configure routing from my local network in `vmbr1` out to the public interface `vmbr0`. My computer has IP `192.168.0.1` on the `vmbr1` interface. I have configured following post routing rule:
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE`

As a test, I am pinging Google DNS server `8.8.4.4` from another computer `192.168.0.101` that has `192.168.0.1` configured as a default gateway.

Using `iptables -t nat -L -v`, I can see some packets are hitting the filter, but by the rate of increase, it is clear the correct packets are not.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 300 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   24  8358 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    vmbr0   anywhere             anywhere
```

From `tcpdump -i vmbr0`, I can see packets are leaving the interface unedited.

```
18:41:35.162157 IP 192.168.0.101 > google-public-dns-b.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1872, seq 996, length 64
18:41:36.170172 IP 192.168.0.101 > google-public-dns-b.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1872, seq 997, length 64
18:41:37.178164 IP 192.168.0.101 > google-public-dns-b.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1872, seq 998, length 64
```

Here is my network configuration:

```
iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  192.168.0.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports dummy0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
#NAT

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  151.80.1.13
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  151.80.1.254
        broadcast  151.80.1.255
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        network 151.80.1.0
```

And routes:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         151.80.1.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
151.80.1.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
```

I have also tried `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` but that didn't work either.

**Edit:** It turns out setting bridge_ports to dummy0 was the problem. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: This is conjecture, but by setting bridge_ports to dummy0, the kernel was probably treating the packet as being internally generated, in which case it hits the OUTPUT chain of the nat table, not the POSTROUTING chain.